# Is swagger UI must for deployment of webapi on Azure API APP?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, swagger-ui, azure-api-apps

I am playing around API APP and any how I am getting error 500 in Swagger UI creation. I am getting same error 500 while deploying on API APP. I was wondering if these two are interrelated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer, `Swagger UI` is absolutely not required for WebAPI.

`Swagger UI` is only an **API documentation framework** which is built for **any Restful web service**

The .NET version of it is `SwashBuckle` (https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle)

You can use any documentation framework or build the documentation on your own. But `Swagger UI` cannot be the reason of your `500 server error`.

Hope it helps.